# counting ternary string witout substring "00"

Tags: combinatorics

I know there is recurence solution, but thats not what I am interested in, I want pure combinatorial solution, similar to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576892/combinatorial-expression-for-all-ternary-strings-that-dont-have-consecutive-1s?noredirect=1#comment3210032_1576892).
What I tried and started with but never realy finished was:

I know all count of all ternary strings is $3^n$ where n is length of string,
so my plan is to subtract $T_n$ from $S_n$ where $T_n$ is number of all ternary strings **with** "00" substring, I am only able to count part of $T_n$ as it is very problematic since many of those cases overlap. Maybe I am supposed to use inclusion/exclusion principle but I dont know how to use it exactly, I am only aware that something like that exist and maybe could be useful here, but even there you have to count those overlappign cases.

Anyone could give me a hit how to solve it **without** any recursion ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of strings lenght $n$ with no consecutive zeros](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559258/number-of-strings-lenght-n-with-no-consecutive-zeros)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many have $k$ zeroes?

First, select the places where your zeroes are going to go. This problem is choosing $k$ spots, out of $n$, so that no two are consecutive. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1030161/33907) is a solution to that problem, it turns out to be $\binom{n-k+1}{k}$.

After this there are $2^{n-k}$ ways to select the other positions (they can be $1$ or $2$).

Therefore we obtain

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\lceil n/2 \rceil}\binom{n-k+1}{k}2^{n-k}$$

Comment: what if you just chosen 011110 string, yes you did chose 2 zeros but they are not together, what am I missing ? and why are we summing to n/2, what if n is odd

Comment: We need for all the zeroes to be distance at least $1$ apart, so we have to choose non-consecutive zeroes.  We are summing to $\frac{n}{2}$ because that is the maximum number of zeroes we can have, any more and it is impossible for them to not be conecutive.

Comment: actually this formula doesnt work take n=3 it gives you 20, but it should be 22, as 27 is all possible - 5 that contain 00 as substring http://textmechanic.com/Combination-Generator.html

Comment: which is correct right?

Comment: no, formula gives you 20 it shoudl be 22

Comment: 010 and 020 doesnt have 00

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. It should have been up to $\lceil n/2 \rceil$

Comment: By the way, the recursion is just $f_n=2(f_{n-1}+f_{n-2})$

Comment: And the closed formula is $f(n) = ((\sqrt{3}-3) (1-\sqrt{3}))^n+(9+5 \sqrt{3}) (1+\sqrt{}))^n)/(6 (1+\sqrt{3}))$

Comment: Without a recursion also?

Comment: yep, i got closed formula thats how I checked

Comment: yep, without recursion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33189/discussion-between-lllook-and-dream).